# CameraX issue on Samsung A51 :- No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 0. May be attempting to bind too many use cases

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I have integrated the CameraX library in my application, Only the Samsung A51 device is having trouble with the camera it gives the following error and the screen turns black `No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 0.  Maybe attempting to bind too many use cases.`

I'm using following code to bind camera use cases from the CameraX sample app

```
/** Declare and bind preview, capture and analysis use cases */
    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }

        val screenAspectRatio = aspectRatio(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        
        val rotation = viewFinder.display.rotation

        // CameraProvider
        val cameraProvider = cameraProvider
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")

        // CameraSelector
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()

        // Preview
        preview = Preview.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            // Set initial target rotation
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()

        val builder = ImageCapture.Builder()
        
            val hdrImageCaptureExtender = HdrImageCaptureExtender.create(builder)
            if (hdrImageCaptureExtender.isExtensionAvailable(cameraSelector)) {
                hdrImageCaptureExtender.enableExtension(cameraSelector)
            }
        
        // ImageCapture
        imageCapture = builder
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config, but letting
            // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits our use cases
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .setFlashMode(isFlashOn)
            // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
            // during the lifecycle of this use case
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()

        // ImageAnalysis
        imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
            // during the lifecycle of this use case
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()
        // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance


        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        try {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
            )
            camera?.cameraControl?.enableTorch(isFlashOn == ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON)

            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Timber.e("ScanQRFragment -> Error in camera initialization bindCameraUseCases: ${exc.stackTraceToString()}")
        }
    }
```

It works fine on all other devices. what could be the issue? Any help suggestions are welcome.

Note:- Earlier this was working and it stopped suddenly.

Comment: You may have such problem when you insist on the aspect ration that is derived from the screen dimensions. The camera may simply have no such mode.

Comment: @AlexCohn - Do you mean I should keep the aspect ratio constant? There are only 2 values for the aspect ratio `RATIO_4_3 ` and `RATIO_16_9 `

Comment: First of all, check what happens on your A51 if you choose 16:9. If the black screen is gone, decide whether you prefer to work with `RATIO_16_9` as the last resort, if the *No supported surface combination is found* appears, or maybe it's the good initial guess.